# mysql, How to sum a value in an array which stored as a field value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The user table is like this:

```
user_id  |  key     |   value
1          option      $array
2          other        abc
2         option      $array
```

I need to query all user's option field,  the value is an array like this:

```
$array=array('item_id'=>123, 'key1'=>'abc', 'key2'=>'1', 'key3'=>'5',)
```

Then, to sum all value of key2 in this array.

The only way I can think of is to make a virtual table with each array as one row. Perhaps it's not possible. Then, how can I make the sum for all user's key2 in option field ?

Comment: Does it needs to be in the query itself, or is it no problem if some logic is used outside the query?

Comment: it doesn't matter how to do it, I just need the total value of key2,and I will need to do the SUM repeatedly when a user saved some new information.

Comment: Would you be able to post a snippet of data from the database?

Comment: When I query the option field, the $array is the result I get from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE key = 'option'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    
   $array_sum_values[] = $row['value']['key2']; //We are creating a new array. }

$result = array_sum($array_sum_values);
```

if i understood you exactly here is the solution.

And alternatively,

```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE key = 'option'");
 $array_sum = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    
   $array_sum += $row['value']['key2']; //We are creating a new array.}
```

Comment: Remove the [] from $array_sum_values? To give the total sum?

Comment: no. we created a new array $array_sum_values. And when we created our array. We sum the each values in array with array_sum

Comment: Ah - missed the last line. Yes - your answer is right, but why not simply sum in the first step, and skip the second array? Cleaner and saves memory/time.

Comment: i added alternative Robbie. Thank you.

Comment: This is exactly the formula I need.

Comment: It's 2012 and `mysql_query` would like to go live in an old age home and watch Matlock re-runs between long naps in a rocking chair. Please **do not use** this method in new applications. Using it in answers sets a very bad example for people new to PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Cihan's answer (summing each row), or creating a view in the database (and the view will need to understand the serialisation of the array) then the fastest way would be to store the data "properly" and not in a munged field like that.

If you want fast and regular summing, create a second table:

```
user_id  |  key     |   array_key | value 
1          option      item_id        123
1          option      key1           abc 
1          option      key2           2
2          other       NULL           123
2          option      item_id        456
```

You could leave array_key blank (or NULL) if it's not an array.

Will require a little bit of rethinking and possibly restructuring some of the code, but it'll be cleaner, easier to debug and ultimately faster if you're summing a lot. The downside it more rows to update when creating a new entry.

You can use GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT if you want the single rows.

Comment: the reason I choose to save data as a field in user table is because the usertable is native wordpress table, caching and other related jobs  will be take care of by wordpress itself. If I create a new table, I will do all the job by myself. Maybe I need to rethink.

Comment: It's all good. Start with getting it to work simply first, then improve from there when you need to.